# Unable to export or import workflows | Power centre (Informatica )|

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

I have recently installed Informatica 10.4 -> Power centre 10.4

After connecting to repository -> trying to open folder to take export of workflow
my application crashes and closed immediately

Can some one tell me why it is not allowing me to take export and same happen with import
it crashes

Any fix for it

Comment: Its related to infa client. Most of the time this is because of 1. Not enough RAM allocated. Pls check if you have at least 4GB of available RAM in the client machine. 2. Second reason may be the user you are using is not same user that installed the client. so you need full permission on infa client executables.

Comment: @KoushikRoy : Can you tell me how to get executable permission

Comment: Ask windows admin to grant full permission on infa client folder. It should be available in infa installation directory like c:/program files/informatica...